# How to write Yara script that creates a rule to match/detect strings contained within a file to another directory which contains a lot of such files?

Tags: rules, malware, malware-detection, soc, yara

1. The malware is of PE type. Use the magic bytes for this file type.
2. To create a rule with a lot of strings it may be useful to write a script that creates the rule for you.
3. The strings found through intelligence may be present in other files in isolation. To make sure you have a match with the malware, it may be necessary to use all of them.

I suppose here, we have to use the condition 'all of them'. But how would I take the input of the strings contained within file into my `.yara` file?

Example this is my File path of the file which contains all the Strings that are to be compared -->

```
/home/student/Desktop/intel/strings.txt
```

Question -->
Write a Yara rule capable of detecting files that are actually malware in the
`/home/student/Desktop/suspicious` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file handling in python to create set of strings for your yara rule.

```
with open("strings.txt","r") as f:
    data=f.read().splitlines()

with open("new1.txt", "w") as t:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        t.write("$s"+str(i)+"="+"\""+str(data[i])+"\""+"\n")
```

For the PE type malware the magic byte is "MZ" so,you need to include this additional string as

> $mz="MZ"

After creating all you strings, the condition should be

> $mz at 0 and all of them